# Complex sum in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, grouping, aggregation

Suppose I have:

```
A       B  
andy    10
andy    20
andy    30
andy    40
paul    10
paul    50
ryan    3
```

... and I want the result to be:

```
A       B       C
andy    10      10
andy    20      30
andy    30      60
andy    40      100
paul    10      10
paul    50      60
ryan    3       3
```

What query will achieve this for me? Think of C as a cumulative frequency.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: I'm working in Access

Comment: People still uses Access??? Not sure if window functions work on it, but you can try...

Comment: Perhaps you can use DSum. See this link. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290136

It was the first thing that came up when I googled it. Ironically DSum in MS Access has been around far longer than analytical functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it.. untested suggestion... a sub-select totals up the relevant values where they match and are in order before the current line...

```
SELECT
  name as A, 
  value as B,
  ( SELECT sum(value) FROM the_table t2 WHERE t2.name=t1.name 
    AND t2.second_order_field<=t1.second_order_field ) as C
FROM the_table t1
ORDER BY t1.name,t1.second_order_field
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting something like a unique ID for second_order_field, which looks good to me.